# Customers can't register

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-account, register

My customers are no longer able to register on my site. When submitting the site simply reloads. I have seen similar threads, but my package already have the FormKey request. My Magento version is 1.9.0.1. Below is my code.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
   <div class="fieldset">
      <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please provide any errors you're seeing. To just say "it doesn't work" makes it hard to debug.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the description. When submitting the form, the site simply reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as below and try again

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
   <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
   <div class="fieldset">
      <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
```

Comment: I tried changing this without any luck in the following path: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form

Answer (score 1):

Check form key in

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

And also

app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml